# how to flip the div using css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to flip the div on hover ..I take help from this example 
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/
But still I am not able to flip my div on hover ..here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/d13cead3/

```
.front{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.front:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#container{
   perspective: 1000;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#innercontainer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 5.0s linear;
}

.back{
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: You can do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/d13cead3/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using all the necessary pieces from the example you linked to. I updated it a bit to more closely match your example:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bacerivopo/edit?html,css,js,output)

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="innercontainer">
  <div class="front face">
    FRONT
  </div>
  <div class="back face">
    BACK
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  perspective: 1000;
}
.innercontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
.container:hover .innercontainer {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00F;
}
.face.front{
  background-color: #F00;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: As a side note - this doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera look okay, though.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#innercontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#container:hover #innercontainer {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
.front {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="innercontainer" class="shadow">
    <div  class="front face">
    front
    </div>
    <div  class="back face ceneter">
      back
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something like that with a step by step explanation.

Not sure why this question has the jQuery tag, it's sure much preferable to use css for just hover functionality in this case.

In the codepen link i am using keyframes, all you would have to change is the following:

```
.card:hover {transform:rotateX(180deg);
```

Go to line 15 and put that in, overwriting the "animation: animation 30s infinite;"

You can also play around with the transform origin property a bit, I haven't got it on default.

Link to the pen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/QjZGjV